# Closing WPF program from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with a class that is inheriting my main window class. I am attempting to close out my Window, but it seems to not be working and provides no error. Maybe I do not understand the way this inheritance works, but please help me understand.

I am only inheriting my MainWindow class to try to gain access to my close method. If this isn't the best approach, please let me know.

Main Window Class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected void CloseProgram()
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void Go_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExcelOperations temp = new ExcelOperations();
        temp.Begin();
    }
}
```

From my other class:

```
class ExcelOperations : MainWindow
{

    private void MethodName()
    {
        try
        {
            // My Code Here
        }
        catch
        {
            // Show Error Message
            // I have tried this.Close(); but it does nothing
            this.CloseProgram(); // This also seems to do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and the instance is ExcelOperations?  can you show how you create the window?  Does the CloseProgram() work if MainWindow is instantiated?

Comment: Are you trying to quit the whole program because you could just do Environment.Exit(1);

Comment: we all assume your class ExcelOperations is public correct???

Comment: @TMcKeown - Code has been updated to show how I call ExcelOperations

Comment: confused... so there is an existing window open of type MainWindow, then you create a NEW instance of ExcelOperations... and that is the window that won't close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple ways you could do this, but in general I wouldn't put a class in charge of ending your application.

You could still handle the error in the class (to display an error), but then throw the exception up the chain, so the `click` event can close the form.

```
private void MethodName()
{
    try
    {
        // My Code Here
    }
    catch
    {
        // Show Error Message
        throw;
    }
}
```

Back in your main window:

```
private void Go_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ExcelOperations temp = new ExcelOperations();
        temp.Begin();
    }
    catch
    {
        // close the program
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

Servy provided an excellent explanation of why you're having an issue.

> It's because ExcelOperations is never shown. He thinks that by inheriting the main window he's able to manipulate it, simply because he has access to the appropriate methods, but it's actually manipulating (i.e., closing) a second window that was never shown in the first place.

So `ExcelOperations` shouldn't inherit from `MainWindow` at all *(I know you were just doing that to try and close from the class)*, and that particular logic should remain within MainWindow itself.

Comment: there is no error and this isn't the answer to his ACTUAL question.

Comment: @TMcKeown There most certainly *is* an error, it's just being swallowed, and this is most certainly the correct solution to the OP's problem, although it could benefit from an explanation as to why the OP's attempt isn't working.

Comment: how do you know there is an exception?

Comment: @TMcKeown Because he's only running this code in a `catch` block.

Comment: lol, ahhh  yes.  That completely escaped me.  Ok, I still don't think that explains/has anything to do with why Close() isn't closing.  The code is being executed.

Comment: @TMcKeown It's because `ExcelOperations` is never shown.  He thinks that by inheriting the main window  he's able to manipulate it, simply because he has access to the appropriate methods, but it's actually mainpulating (i.e., closing) a second window that was never shown in the first place.

Comment: ok thanks!  I was so hung up on the 2 windows.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main windows. The MainWindow that is being created when you start the app and the ExcelOperations window that you are creating when the Go_Button_Click event is fired.

If you want to explicitly shutdown the application, the [Application.Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)() method will do that for you.

You can also control how the application shuts down via the [ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `MainWindow` class to your 2nd `ExcelOperations` class ...and do not inherit from `MainWindow`:

```
class ExcelOperations
{
    private MainWindow parent;

    public ExcelOperations(MainWindow parent)
    {
      this.parent = parent;
    }

    private void MethodName()
    {
        try
        {
            // My Code Here
        }
        catch
        {
            // Show Error Message
            parent.Close();
        }
    }
}
```